# How should i use group by and sum on different values of list of models using linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum

I have FinalCons which is a list of my model class

```
List<ItemsConsumed> FinalCons = new List<ItemsConsumed>();
```

This FinalCons has a list of Item Consumed by the persons, Like

[Content of FinalCons List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jsEx.png)

And I want List in which the data should be like this,
[Needed List after group by and sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVmmr.png)

I tried this, But sum is not calculating properly.

```
 var itemcomsumed = FinalCons.OrderBy(x => x.PersonalID).ToList().GroupBy(x => x.PersonalID)
            .Select(x => new 
            { 
                consumption = x.Sum(a => a.Consumption), 
                PersonalID= x.Select(a => (int)a.PersonalID), 
                ItemID = x.Select(a => (int)a.ItemID)
            });
```

i also tried to get the required result from this, but this also not giving me the correct result.

```
var itemCon = FinalCons.GroupBy(ic => new { ic.PersonalID}).Select(ic => new ItemsConsumed
           {
              PersonalID=ic.Key.PersonalID,
               ItemID = ic.FirstOrDefault().ItemID,
               Consumption=ic.Sum(c=>c.Qty)
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: The `sum` *should* be correct. I dont see a problem with the first code except your `.Select()` s should have a `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: When i am adding the content of first itemcomsumed to a list it shows me an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int'. ". So i write the code for itemCon using FirstOrDefault().But not giving the proper result.It gives only two rows for each ID.But i Need it filter by itemID also..Not getting how to write a linq query for this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [final list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVmmr.png) is grouped by both `PersonalID` and `ItemID`,

```
<Personal ID, Item ID, Consumption>

<1 , 4 , 1>        <1 , 4 , 2>         
<1 , 4 , 1>        <1 , 5 , 1>         
<1 , 5 , 1>        <2 , 4 , 1>         
<2 , 4 , 1>        <2 , 5 , 2>        
<2 , 5 , 2>
```

Use the below grouping logic

```
var itemConsumed = FinalCons
                   .GroupBy(x => new { 
                               x.PersonalID, 
                               x.ItemID 
                   }) //group by both PersonalID and ItemID
                   .Select(x => new 
                   { 
                       PersonalID= x.Key.PersonalID, 
                       ItemID = x.Key.ItemID,
                       Consumption = x.Sum(a => a.Consumption)
                   })
                   .OrderBy(x => x.PersonalID).ThenBy(y=>y.ItemID);
                     //order by Personal ID and then by Item ID
```